# Как использовать данные присланные из php в формате json?

Tags: php, json

В php формирую массив и создаю ассоциативный массив, затем кодирую его в формат json.

```
<?php
$somearray = array();
$somearray[0] = $row_dle_post['full_story'];
$somearray[1] = $tpl->result['content'];
echo json_encode(array('content' => $somearray[0], 'comments' => $somearray[1])); 
?>
```

Затем пытаюсь вывести через точку и вылетает undefined, хотя если вывести целиком alert(data), то выводится всё, что и отправлялось в должном формате.

```
    $( ".good" ).click(function() {
    $.post('../phpfile.php',  function(data) {
    alert(data.content); });  
    });
```

Данные при alert(data)

```
{"content":"mytext","comments":"another text"}
```

Вообщем, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1):

решил проблему

$.post( "test.php", { func: "getNameAndTime" }, function( data ) {
  console.log( data.name ); // John
  console.log( data.time ); // 2pm
}, "json");

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/